# 02 Honda Odyssey transmission revs up or doesn't engage at 25 when off gas and up-shifting

Tags: honda, transmission, troubleshooting, throttle, throttle-position-sensor

my 02  Honda Odyssey transmission revs up or doesn't engage at 25 when off gas and up-shifting. Here is what happens in steps:

1. accelerate to 25 in second gear
2. off gas and upshift to third
3. immediately step on throttle
4. car revs up without accelerating

My transmission shop fixed this by adjusting the throttle cable to have 10mm of play in it, however I do not like an unresponsive gas pedal. is there an alternative solution to this problem? I heard that one solution would be to adjust the throttle position sensor by loosening it and turning it.

Comment: Check/test your engine mounts, when you push in the clutch and your acceleration goes from 'x' to 0, your engine moves, and then you hit the gas and switch to third gear, you go back from 0 to 'y', the engine moves again. Your shift from second gear to third is probably taking long enough that the engine has moved but not resettled and is pulling on the throttle cable.

Comment: I just replace the side engine mount and the front one is new. Maybe others are also worn.Would the problem be considered a transmission problem? When the car goes to wide open throttle under my conditions, the transmission does not shift. I would think that going to wide open throttle should cause a downshift, or no shift, but not going into neutral. Do you think the problem is related to throttle linkage, or would there be some other problem? I am completely stumped.

Comment: Should I combine both questions?